# SQL Return Value of Zero so filter remains

Tags: sql, sql-server

The query below works great except for one thing. 
I am using the column as "WorkStream" as a filter in my end user report. Since it is a filter I need it to be there regardless of whether or not the query returns anything.
Of course I have to use the where clause as a filter within the query so that only certain tasks are returned. 
The trouble is that when I have a workstream without any task_Significance items the workstream is removed and the report filter (Workstream) does not work.

What I need is a table that looks like this but if I have a missing workstream then it would put "0's" all the way across. But only if the workstream is missing would it return ONLY the filter name (so the report would have the filter and just show and empty table below the filter in the final report.

[image]

This is my code:

```
        SELECT
     p.[Workstream]
    ,T.[Task_Significance]
    ,COUNT(1) AS Total
    ,SUM(case when T.[TaskPercentCompleted] >= 100 then 1 else 0 end) AS Actual
    ,SUM(case when T.[TaskFinishDate] <= DATEADD(DAY, 8-DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()), Convert(date,getdate())) then 1 else 0 end) AS Planned
    FROM [psmado].[dbo].[MSP_EpmProject_UserView] as P
       join   [PSMADO].[dbo].[MSP_EpmTask_UserView] as T
      On T.[projectUID] = P.[projectUID]
    WHERE 
      [Task_Significance] IN('Application', 'Data', 'Interface', 'End User Compute', 'Network', 'Compute Package', 'Data Center', 'CREWS Sites', 'App Design Review', 'Infra Design Review')
    GROUP BY   p.[EnterpriseProjectTypeUID], p.[Workstream],T.[Task_Significance]
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `left join` and move your `where` clause to the `on` clause. This will return all `p.[Workstream]` and those `t.Task_Significance` that are in your `in()` list.

You can use [**`coalesce()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) or [**`isnull()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) to substitute a value for `null` when there are no matching `t.Task_Significance`.

```
select 
    p.[Workstream]
  , coalesce(T.[Task_Significance], 'none') as Task_Significance
  , count(1) as Total
  , sum(case when T.[TaskPercentCompleted] >= 100 then 1 else 0 end) as Actual
  , sum(case when T.[TaskFinishDate] 
      <= dateadd(day, 8 - datepart(dw, getdate()), Convert(date, getdate())) 
        then 1 else 0 end) as Planned
from [psmado].[dbo].[msp_EpmProject_UserView] as P
  left join [psmado].[dbo].[msp_EpmTask_UserView] as T 
    on T.[projectuid] = P.[projectuid] 
   and [Task_Significance] in ('Application', 'Data', 'Interface'
    , 'End User Compute', 'Network', 'Compute Package', 'Data Center'
    , 'crews Sites', 'App Design Review', 'Infra Design Review')
group by 
    p.[EnterpriseProjectTypeuid]
  , p.[Workstream]
  , T.[Task_Significance]
```